# how to add dot in the active nav menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, stack, wp-nav-menu-item

hello  this is my nav menu code i've added animation like a dot move along when i hover over my nav menu. but i don't know how to make that dot to be static in the active menu .

ex: (menu1) this is my menu , when it'active i want that dot beside my menu (menu1.) like this kind of i want
if anyone find the solution please give me the code

```css
body {
  font-family: "Sprint Sans Ofc";
}
.navMenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  White-space:nowrap;
  padding-right:20px;
  padding left:30px;
}

.navMenu a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-transform: captilalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.navMenu a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
.navMenu a:active {
    color:#000000;
}

.navMenu .dot {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #D61E39;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin:-44px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
  transform: translateX(30px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.navMenu a:nth-child(1):hover ~ .dot {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
  transform: translateX(145px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navMenu a:nth-child(2):hover ~ .dot {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(110px);
  transform: translateX(280px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navMenu a:nth-child(3):hover ~ .dot {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
  transform: translateX(415px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navMenu a:nth-child(4):hover ~ .dot {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(285px);
  transform: translateX(550px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
navMenu a:nth-child(1):active ~ .dot {
  position: relative;
  left:40px;
  bottom:10px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.navMenu a:nth-child(1):active ~ .dot {
    left:20px;
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navMenu">
      <a href="#">menu1</a>
      <a href="#">menu2</a>
      <a href="#">menu3</a>
      <a href="#">menu4</a>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

Comment: Could you clarify that you do mean :active (the pseudo class e.g. when the user has pressed the mousebutton but no yet clicked as opposed to a .active class put there e.g. through JS when the user has clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The challenge with your `.dot` element is to apply the CSS styles (especially the `transform` values) in a way, that both `hover` and `active` states are handled correctly.

In order to achieve this, I'm using CSS selectors like this one:

```css
.navMenu a:nth-child(2):hover~.dot,
.navMenu:not(:hover) a:nth-child(2).active~.dot {
```

Basically, this means, do the animation if either

- the element is currently being hovered
- or the link is active (i.e. it was clicked before), **BUT** with the limitation that the parent `.navMenu` is currently not being hovered.

The second rule guarantees, that a `hover` has the highest priority when setting the destination of the `.dot` element (especially, this makes the dot move away from the currently active item). Otherwise, the dot wouldn't move and stick to the `.active` menu item.

Check out my approach below (btw, no need for `-webkit` properties here):

```js
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('nav a')

anchors.forEach(anchor => anchor.addEventListener("click", onClick));

function onClick(e) {
  anchors.forEach(achor => achor.classList.remove('active'))
  e.target.classList.add('active')
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Sprint Sans Ofc";
}

.navMenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  White-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding left: 30px;
}

.navMenu a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-transform: captilalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.navMenu a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

.navMenu a:active {
  color: #000000;
}

.navMenu .dot {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #D61E39;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: -44px;
  transform: translateX(-30px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.navMenu a:nth-child(1):hover~.dot,
.navMenu:not(:hover) a:nth-child(1).active~.dot {
  transform: translateX(145px);
}

.navMenu a:nth-child(2):hover~.dot,
.navMenu:not(:hover) a:nth-child(2).active~.dot {
  transform: translateX(280px);
}

.navMenu a:nth-child(3):hover~.dot,
.navMenu:not(:hover) a:nth-child(3).active~.dot {
  transform: translateX(415px);
}

.navMenu a:nth-child(4):hover~.dot,
.navMenu:not(:hover) a:nth-child(4).active~.dot {
  transform: translateX(550px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navMenu">
    <a href="#">menu1</a>
    <a href="#">menu2</a>
    <a href="#">menu3</a>
    <a href="#">menu4</a>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: can you explain how to add this in my WordPress nav menu? there is no option to add javascript in nav menu

Comment: Inorder to add this to the wordpress nav menu, you would need to add this code to the header.php file for the theme assuming that your theme has the navigation under the header.php section.